# Capturing a class inside a table tag and capturing multiple items

Tags: javascript, html

So let's say I have multiple items with multiple quantities. I want to get that quantity with a variable and then print the quantities with a  sentence. I know there are some syntax problems here but I am trying to give a general idea. It also doesn't have to be .write as long as it creates a sentence.

```
<td class="v1_shop_cart_articles_col_qty">
            2

</td>
<td class="v1_shop_cart_articles_col_qty">
            5

</td>
<script>
    var qty = document.getElementsByClassName('v1_shop_cart_articles_col_qty');
    for(var i=0; i<qty.length; i++) { 
    document.write(' A order was placed  with a quantity  of'+qty[i]+'.'); 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: p.s.  for clarification it should write several sentences  i.e.       A order was placed  with a quantity  of 2. A order was placed  with a quantity  of 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. You can get the contents of each element with `innerHTML`, and convert it to an integer with `parseInt()`, e.g.:

```
for(var i=0; i<qty.length; i++) {
  document.write('An order was placed with a quantity of ' +
                 parseInt(qty[i].innerHTML, 10) +
                 '.'); 
}
```

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/BirIo

Comment: Why the 10 after the innerHTML?

Comment: It's the radix. We're parsing decimal strings. We could pass `16` to parse hex, etc. Quoting the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), "**Always specify this parameter** to eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee predictable behavior. Different implementations produce different results when a radix is not specified."